# install Jenkins & its plugins in Docker,then save a new image to be used in the other offline PC

Tags: docker, jenkins, svn, msbuild, offline

Installl Jenkins and its plugins in an offline pc is difficult.
can I install Jenkins in Docked, intall all the plugins needed in a PC, and then save this new image and copy it to the other PC which is offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to mound local directory wit Jenkins and install plugins.

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD/:/var/jenkins_home -p 8081:8080 jenkins/jenkins
```

Once you mount host directory, then install required plugging, create Dockerfile like below

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
COPY plugins /var/jenkins_home/plugins/
```

Then build this Dockerfile,

```
docker build -t my_custom_jenkins .
```

Then you can share this image with others and it will contain all plugins.

If you need full configuration then use below option

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
COPY . /var/jenkins_home/plugins/
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I'm using (DockerToolbox-19.03.1.exe)Docker Quickstart Terminal on Windows. are the commands the same as you said?

Comment: you might need a bit different from `-v $PWD/:/var/jenkins_home` to deal in window, just mount `-v C:/Yourpath/:/var/jenkins_home

Comment: The reason I chose this method is I found if I intalled jenkins-2.235.1 on Windows but not docker in Windows, and then follow (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#offline-jenkins-installation) is quite difficult.
Do you know which way is better to install jenkins and its plugins in Offline PC?

Comment: C:/Yourpath/:/var/jenkins_home
Yourpath can be anypath?or the installed docker.exe Path which is F:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox for me?

Comment: `C:/Yourpath/:` this can be any path on your host OS

Comment: docker pull jenkinsci/blueocean
then I follow (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#on-windows)
so here I should use your command after "docker volume create jenkins-data", right?
there is no need to run   docker:dind ?

Comment: its used to copy and build custom docker image with plugin, so you can share image with other with pre-existing pluging.

Comment: thank you, so I will try docker, not (jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#offline-jenkins-installation)

Comment: docker container run --name jenkins-blueocean -it --rm -v F:/jenkins_blueocean/:/var/jenkins_home --detach --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro --publish 1122:8080 --publish 50000:50000 jenkinsci/blueocean
``````````I got error: 
F:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/jenkins_home.
See 'F:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

Comment: $ docker container run --name jenkins-blueocean -it --rm -v /F/jenkins_blueocean:/var/jenkins_home --detach --network j
enkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 --volume jenk
ins-data:/var/jenkins_home --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro --publish 1122:8080 --publish 50000:50000 jen
kinsci/blueocean
F:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Duplicate mount point: /var/jenkins_home.
See 'F:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

Comment: F:/jenkins_blueocean is a new created empty directory.

Comment: I tried docker commit, then save and load in offline pc.
This image donot contain the plugins i intalled in the online pc.

Comment: $ docker run -it --rm -v /F/jenkins_blueocean:/var/jenkins_home -p 1122:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?········I run this after clean all the created network and volume

Comment: A@pc2 MINGW64 /f/jenkins_blueocean
$ docker build -t my_custom_jenkins .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
 ---> 69b6d837d67b
Step 2/2 : COPY . /var/jenkins_home/
 ---> b1bf0ef60bff
Successfully built b1bf0ef60bff
Successfully tagged my_custom_jenkins:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.

Comment: A@pc2 MINGW64 /f/jenkins_blueocean
$ docker build -t my_custom_jenkins2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
 ---> 69b6d837d67b
Step 2/2 : COPY plugins /var/jenkins_home/plugins/
COPY failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder935213426/plugins: no such file or directory

Comment: The seems like mounting with window

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62778288/copy-plugins-txt-in-jenkins-in-docker-in-windows-failed
Please see this topic, I show the detail here. Thank you.

Comment: ```
$ docker run -it --rm -v F:/Yourpath/:/var/jenkins_home -p 1133:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean
```
F:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/jenkins_home.
See 'F:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

Comment: ```$ docker run -it --rm -v /F/jenkins_blueocean:/var/jenkins_home -p 1133:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean```
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?