# "COPY plugins.txt" in Jenkins in Docker in Windows failed

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, plugins

```
docker pull jenkinsci/blueocean

docker network create jenkins

docker volume create jenkins-docker-certs
docker volume create jenkins-data

docker container run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach --privileged --network jenkins --network-alias docker --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home docker:dind

docker container run --name jenkins-blueocean --rm --detach --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro --publish 1122:8080 --publish 50000:50000 jenkinsci/blueocean
```

then,

```
//method 1, failed
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Step 2/3 : COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder945145338/plugins.txt: no such file or directory
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//method 2, failed
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
COPY plugins /var/jenkins_home/plugins/

//method 3, warning and plugins still not include
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean:latest
COPY . /var/jenkins_home/plugins/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
A@pc2 MINGW64 /f/jenkins_blueocean $ docker build -t my_custom_jenkins . Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048kB Step 1/2 : FROM jenkinsci/blueocean:latest ---> 69b6d837d67b Step 2/2 : COPY . /var/jenkins_home/ ---> b1bf0ef60bff Successfully built b1bf0ef60bff Successfully tagged my_custom_jenkins:latest SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I tried the above COPY cmd in (DockerToolbox-19.03.1.exe)Docker Quickstart Terminal & Windows PowerShell(Admin), both failed...
the error info are sth like this:

```
Step 2/3 : COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder945145338/plugins.txt: no such file or directory
```

I want to install Jenkins and the needed plugins in Docker in Windows, and then save the Jenkins&all the plugins use Docker, in order to use the Jenkins&all the plugins in another Offline PC.

Comment: I create a file named Dockerfile in E:\a, then in (DockerToolbox-19.03.1.exe)Docker Quickstart Terminal & Windows PowerShell(Admin), use "docker build -t my_custom_jenkins ."

Comment: do not use named volume, use bind host and then build will work. I do not think plugin is exist on your Host.

Comment: thank you, could you please show me an example or give me a link to some direct tutorial?
I followed:(jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#on-windows)(https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker)

Comment: first better to read about bind volume, you can look into this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you store plugins.txt file?

It should exist in the same folder with Dockerfile.